# Isomorphism and identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I think the idea here is to prove that $\{T(v) \mid v\in \beta\}$ is also a basis for $W$ thus we could order it to basis $\gamma$ such that $[T]$ is the identity matrix. But I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Please take the time to enter critical parts of your question—here basically most of your question—as text instead of pasting a picture of it. This question is incomprehensible with images disabled. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. You can find a quick reference to formattnfig mathematical expressions using MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I understood, thank you amd!

Answer (score 4):

If $(T)$ is the identity matrix in some basis, then obviously, it's an isomorphism. For the converse, let $T\in \mathcal L(V,W)$ an isomorphism. If $\mathcal V=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$, then $\mathcal W=\{ T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$ is a basis of $W$ (why?) and $(T)_{\mathcal V}^{\mathcal W}$ is the identity matrix.

---

**Added**

*Proof of $\mathcal W$ a basis of $W$.* It's enough to prove that they are independent.
\begin{align*}
\alpha _1T(v_1)+...+\alpha _nT(v_n)=0&\implies T(\alpha _1v_1+...+\alpha _n v_n)=0\\
&\underset{\text{why?}}{\implies }\alpha _1v_1+...\alpha _nv_n=0. 
\end{align*}
I let you conclude.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly where I don't know how to proceed. Why W is a basis for W？

Comment: @meow123: I edited my answer.

Comment: @Surb why does proving the fact that $\mathcal{W}$ is a basis of W imply that $[T]$ is identity matrix?